# What are excellent Artifical Intelligence Journals?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I've become interested in AI and want to keep up with the latest AI research. Can someone recommend the top 2-3 AI journals I should read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some good journals are:

- [Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research](http://www.jair.org/) (JAIR)
- [Artificial Intelligence](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/journaldescription.cws_home/505601/description#description)

Also [JMLR](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/) (Journal of Machine Learning Research) is a **GREAT** journal (as mentioned in another post), but it deals only with Machine Learning (a subset of AI) and not with other AI related fields.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit broader in scope for your interests but take a look at the [Journal of Machine Learning Research](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/) and it's sister software repository [Machine learning open source software](http://mloss.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know the latest advances in AI you should also pay attention to high profile conferences such as:

- [International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence](http://ijcai.org/) (IJCAI)
- [Association for the Advancement of Artificial Intelligence](http://www.aaai.org/home.html) (AAAI)